# javascript return false; is not working on each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have mentioned my code below, i have a problem with return flase; inside a javascript each function

```
$(".current_patient_medicine").each(function (i) {
    var id = this.id;
    var value = $("#" + id).val();
    if (value.trim() == "") {

        check = false;
        alert("Medicine Name cannot left Blank.");
        return false;
    } else {
        check = true;
    }
});
$(".current_patient_medicine_days").each(function (i) {
    var id = this.id;
    var value = $("#" + id).val();
    if (value.trim() == "") {

        check = false;
        alert("Days Field cannot left Blank.");
        return false;
    } else {
        check = true;
    }
});
```

here the first condition alert "Medicine Name cannot left blank" showing well but after that the second alert also showing

Comment: Use `break` instead of `return false` if you don't want to make other loops.

Comment: Nitpick: your code's indentation makes it difficult to read. Have a look at a [Javascript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)

Comment: break must be inside a loop or switch, so it's throwing javascrip  error

Comment: @panther: you can't use a break statent here because this isn't a Javascript loop construct like `for` or `while`.  `.each` in jQuery is a higher-order function; `break` is an illegal statement in this context: http://cl.ly/image/0M3C1o0P280T/Image%202015-02-16%20at%2011.07.22%20PM.png

Comment: works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gnf7ath2/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gnf7ath2/3/ - though there is a issue.. 1) the `check` variable should not be updated in the else condition... also there is no need to use the id selector, you can just use `this.value` or `$(this).val()` to get the value

Comment: @Arun P Johny , it's not working showing both alerts one by one

Comment: @askm3 like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gnf7ath2/5/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You have the `return false` in an inner function call, it wouldn't stop the execution flow of the external function so you need

```
var check = true;
$(".current_patient_medicine").each(function (i) {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value.trim() == "") {
        check = false;
        alert("Medicine Name cannot left Blank.");
        return false;
    }
});
if (!check) {
    return false;
}
$(".current_patient_medicine_days").each(function (i) {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value.trim() == "") {
        check = false;
        alert("Days Field cannot left Blank.");
        return false;
    }
});
if (!check) {
    return false;
}
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var check = true;
  $(".current_patient_medicine").each(function(i) {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value.trim() == "") {
      check = false;
      alert("Medicine Name cannot left Blank.");
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (!check) {
    return false;
  }
  $(".current_patient_medicine_days").each(function(i) {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value.trim() == "") {
      check = false;
      alert("Days Field cannot left Blank.");
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (!check) {
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="m1" class="current_patient_medicine" />
<input id="d1" class="current_patient_medicine_days" />
<br />
<input id="m2" class="current_patient_medicine" />
<input id="d2" class="current_patient_medicine_days" />
<br />
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rule of thumb**: avoid return statements inside $.each statements

**Rethink the solution**:

```
function logic(someArray)
{
    var result = false;
    $.each(someArray, function(index,item){

        if(item == someValue)
        {
           result = true;
        }

    });

    return result;
}
```

This problem costed me a complete day to discover and fix. OMG!

Hope This helps someone.

Comment: so many answers telling where to put the correct return false statement. But nothing worked since the problem was the logic and NOT the implementation. 

This saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for `$.each()`:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

I've slightly simplified your codez:

```
var check = true;

$(".current_patient_medicine").each(function() {
  // The empty string ("") is falsey, so we can remove the comparison.
  // Also, no need to double-select the current element,
  // instead get the val() directly:
  if (! $(this).val().trim()) {
    alert("Medicine Name cannot left Blank.");
    check = false;
    return false;
  }
});

$(".current_patient_medicine_days").each(function() {
  if (! $(this).val().trim()) {
    alert("Days Field cannot left Blank.");
    check = false;
    return false;
  }
});
```

This code will alert the first time it sees an empty `.current_patient_medicine` value, and then it will alert the first time it sees an empty `.current_patient_medicine_days` value.